# string is not fetching selected value

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my VF page :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="bookList">
    <apex:form>
        <br>
        <center>
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!aList}" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputText value="{!myStr}" />
        </center>
        </br>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And this is my Controller :

```
public with sharing class bookList {
    public string myStr {get;set;}
    public string selectedValue {
        get {
            return selectedValue;
        }
        set {
            string selectedValue;
            this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
        }
    }
    public List < selectOption > aList {
        get {
            aList = new List < selectoption > ();
            Schema.describeFieldResult myDesc = Book__c.Type__c.getDescribe();
            list < Schema.PickListEntry > aPickList = myDesc.getPickListValues();
            aList.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: aPickList) {
                aList.add(new selectOption(f.getlabel(), f.getvalue()));
            }
            return aList;
        }
        set {
            List < string > myStrList = new List < String > ();
        }
    }
    public bookList() {
        myStr = selectedValue;
    }
}
```

my requirement is simple, i need to display the value of the string `selectedValue` on the VF page.....but the problem is it is not even storing the selected value..... how can i do that...? i want to avoid hardcoding on VF page...because values for the picklist might change later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="bookList">
    <apex:form id="frmId">
        <br>
        <center>
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!aList}" />
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!bookList}" event="onchange" reRender="frmId"/>
            </apex:selectList> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!myStr}" />
        </center>
        </br>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

it's Controller May like this

```
public with sharing class bookList {
    public string myStr {get;set;}
    public string selectedValue {get; set;}
    public List < selectOption > aList {
        get {
            aList = new List < selectoption > ();
            Schema.describeFieldResult myDesc = Account.CustomerPriority__c.getDescribe();
            list < Schema.PickListEntry > aPickList = myDesc.getPickListValues();
            aList.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: aPickList) {
                aList.add(new selectOption(f.getlabel(), f.getvalue()));
            }
            return aList;
        }
        set {
            List < string > myStrList = new List < String > ();
        }
    }
    public void bookList() {
        system.debug('::::::::;selectedValue::;;;'+selectedValue);
        myStr = selectedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like

```
<apex:form id="frm">
        <br>
        <center>
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!aList}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="frm" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputText value="{!selectedValue}" />
        </center>
        </br>
    </apex:form>
```

Use `apex:actionSupport` here to display updated value.